# SpringRunner.class cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, testing, springrunner

This is my testing code to test my project. I have all the imports in but yet it still can't seem to find the `SpringRunner.class`. Below is my class.

```
package c03xxx.test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import CO3102.hw2.domain.AccountTypes;
import CO3102.hw2.domain.User;
import CO3102.hw2.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Test
    public void testSignUp() throws Exception{
        User u = new User();
        u.setDob("31/12/1999");
        u.setEmail("testEmail@le.ac.uk");
        u.setFav_team("Liverpool");
        u.setNumber_of_friends(0);
        u.setPassword("123456");
        u.setUsername("TESTUSERNAME");
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/newUser"))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
}
```

And this is the error message I am receving:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
SpringRunner cannot be resolved to a type
Class<SpringRunner> cannot be resolved to a type

at c03xxx.test.ApplicationTest.<init>(ApplicationTest.java:20)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConstructorInvocation.proceed(ConstructorInvocation.java:56)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:77)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:333)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:77)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:262)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Here are my gradle dependicies:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-crypto', version: '5.4.2'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") 
    compile group: 'com.qasymphony.qtest', name: 'qtest-sdk-java', version: '1.4.7'    
    compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.3'
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    compile group: 'tangrammer', name: 'java-net-http-client', version: '0.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.6'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.8.0-M1'    
}
```

Is there any reason why this may not be working. Before I had this error I had a mockMvc error which was fixed by adding the `SpringRunner.class` but now this is also not working! If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have **jupiter**, that is **JUnit5**. But import SpringRunner from **JUnit4**.
Actually the whole string:

```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

is not required when you run with JUnit5

Comment: Thank you, although when I remove this I still get the same error. I have removed the import as well.

Comment: Could you please provide: updated code, updated dependencies, updated error stack. If you have the same error, probably you still have some implicit JUnit4 dependency